# JavaCV FFmpegFrameGrabber & Java2DFrameConverter creating weird looking image

Tags: java, ffmpeg, javacv

I'm new to JavaCV, so the issue is probably very obvious. I'm trying to do the easy said, difficult done, task of getting the images and audio from a video so I can start making a video editor. After lots of confusion and errors, I am finally getting a result, but it is as odd as the errors. The image appears to be squished in the x direction, with the extra space to the right being transparent (so the image size matches the video's size). Additionally, it has a lot of extra transparent pixels and is multicolored in an odd way.

What the image should look like: https://gofile.io/d/1lQnNd

What the image looks like: https://gofile.io/d/kc09G7

Here is my code:

```
try {
    FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("C:/Users/mega12345mega/Desktop/Test Files/video.mp4");
    frameGrabber.setFormat("mp4");
    frameGrabber.start();

    int width = frameGrabber.getImageWidth();
    int height = frameGrabber.getImageHeight();
    System.out.println("width: " + width + ", height: " + height);

    Frame frame = frameGrabber.grabImage();
    if (frame == null)
        throw new Exception("Frame is NULL!");
    if (frame.image == null)
        throw new Exception("Frame Image is NULL!");

    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    if (bi == null)
        throw new Exception("bi is NULL!");

    Java2DFrameConverter.copy(frame, bi);
    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("C:/Users/mega12345mega/Desktop/Test Files/img.png"));

    frameGrabber.stop();
    frameGrabber.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new Exception("Error Getting Image", e);
}
```

If you are interested, here is the console:

```
width: 1280, height: 720
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:/Users/mega12345mega/Desktop/Test Files/video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:04.95, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 16375 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 16401 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Additionally, if I just do `frameGrabber.grab()` instead of `frameGrabber.grabImage()` (which I believe leaves out the audio), the frame's image property is null (that is what the `frame.image == null` statement is there for). I am not sure if that belongs in a new question, but help on that is also appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to fix this, but I'm not sure why this works. (Comments about this are appreciated!)

After looking at [this issue](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/845) - though the problem was different - I found that they used this in their code:

```
bi = new Java2DFrameConverter().convert(frame);
```

What I did was this:

```
Java2DFrameConverter.copy(frame, bi);
```

For some reason, this fixes the issue.
Obviously, with the solution, you can remove this line as well:

```
new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```